# Graph not showing on tkinter but still getting implemented

Tags: python-3.x

```
def find_stock(self):
    self.buy_stock = self.buy_choice_entry.get()
    self.buy_choice_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    connection = sqlite3.connect("stocks.db")
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM stockmarket WHERE code=?", (self.buy_stock,))
    self.code_result = c.fetchone()
    print(self.code_result)
    code_value_found = self.code_result is not None
    connection.close()
    if code_value_found:
        self.buy_choice.place_forget()
        self.buy_label.config(text="Stock analytics")
        stock_price = [random.randint(50, int(self.code_result[5])) for i in range(10)]
        days = range(1, len(stock_price) + 1)
        plt.plot(days, stock_price)
        plt.xlabel('Day')
        plt.ylabel('Price')
        plt.title('Stock Price Fluctuations for {}'.format(self.code_result[1]))
        fig = plt.gcf()
        graph = self.frame
        graph.pack()
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=graph)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

The code executes perfectly without throwing any errors but the graph does not show. I think it is something to do with the frame and not being able to access it which is why the graph isnt showing. the master frame is self.parent.